# Ruby after_destroy set a value on child attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

lets say I have 2 models, user and group

```
user belongs_to :group
group has_many :users
```

is there a way to set the user.group attribute to another value before/after a group gets destroyed?

Comment: means you don't want to delete child.

Comment: yes I don't want to delete every user in the group, I instead want to assign it to a default group

Answer (score 0):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users
  before_destroy -> { users.each {|u| u.group = nil; u.save}}

end
```

Comment: I don't want to set it to nil, I want to set it to another value, if I wanted to set it to nil i could use :dependent => :nullify

Comment: please edit the code above to set the value to anything you desire.  I just provided the means to do so

Comment: I did, but then i got a Fixnum Error, because I can't set it to just an Integer, it has to be an instance of group, I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: You can set `u.group_id` to an integer.

Comment: I'm still on this, I did try everything from directly setting a group_id to update_attributes, it doesn't set the group to a default group, at the console i get this "User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`username` = BINARY 'Admin1' AND `users`.`id` != 148) LIMIT 1" so, it doesn't want to update the user, it wants to save a new one, how do i call the update method on it?